# GTK widget dialog does not close

Tags: c++, linux, dialog, widget, gtk

I trying to make simple "message box" dialog with gtk. it's works, but dialog does not close when I click button. (I'm using gtk only fo dialogs. My main window - not gtkWindow, but X11 Glx Window). Here is my code:

```
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,
                                     GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                     GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                                     GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                     "Some text",
                                     g_strerror (errno));

    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
```

If i click "close" button - program run continue, widget dialog lost focus but not closing\hiding. Why? Seems gtk_widget_destroy(dialog) not calling.

p.s. I'm using Linux 64, eclipse, c++

Comment: While the arguments to gtk_message_dialog_new() are a little incorrect. One too many in this case, by adding the required headers and making this a complete function it works. If you can post a [mcve] then it can be checked to find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the message box a modal dialog.

```
GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (NULL,
                                     GTK_DIALOG_MODAL,
                                     GTK_MESSAGE_ERROR,
                                     GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                     "Some text",
                                     g_strerror (errno));
```